# Escape string using RE2::GlobalReplace

Tags: c++, re2

Due to reasons, I am only using RE2 for regex matching in the project.

I am trying to escape specific characters using RE2 library.

```
std::string aInput = "~/Test (Folder)/";
RE2::GlobalReplace( &aInput, "(<|>|\\||\\:|\\(|\\)|&|;|\\s)", "\\\\0" );
```

I know that `\0` is inserting whole matching group but once I am adding an escape symbol I am receiving unexpected result:

> ~/Test\0\0Folder\0

instead of

> ~/Test\ \(Folder\)/

How to insert \ before each matching group using RE2?

PS. RE2::QuoteMeta() is not an option for me as it will escape characters I don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression groups begin with 1, not 0. Besides that you use `"\\\\0"` as the replacement string. This is a literal `"\0"` in your final regex. Replace `"\\\\0"` with `"\\\\\\1"`. This will evaluate to `"\\\1"`, which is a literal \ and the first matching group.

You can design and test regular expressions and the state machines they generate with this [helpful site](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works like a charm.